# Jest does not resolve ESM local imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

I have a Typescript project with two files, `a.ts` and `b.ts`. I import the latter in `a.ts` like this

```
import * from "./b.js"
```

This works fine. Typescript understands. However, when running Jest (using ts-jest), I get

```
Cannot find module './b.js' from 'a.ts'
```

How can I make Jest understand that the .js import is still a .ts file when running the test?

Comment: To the downvoter: what is the problem with this question? So I might clarify/update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found it. I had to add the below to `jest.config.ts`

```
moduleNameMapper: {
   '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
},
```

It maps `.js` filenames to an extensionless version, which Jest (i.e. ts-node under the hood) can then find.

Note: having `preset: 'ts-jest'` is also necessary, but I already had that before.

Answer (score -5):

There are many reasons why the "cannot find module" error can happen in TypeScript:

1. The package is not installed.
2. Something is wrong with the node_modules folder.
3. The package import contains a spelling mistake.
4. Something is wrong with your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Please, at least format your AI-generated answer.